Using libzip in nav2 plugin
I'm trying to use a PyTorch Model as a controller for Nav2. Since the model may vary, I want to load everything from a .zip-archive (model and additional parameters). The Plugin successfully compiles but when I execute navigation, I get the following error:

[controller_server-29] /opt/ros/iron/lib/nav2_controller/controller_server: symbol lookup error: /home/user/Documents/Programming/ros2_home_iron/Documents/ros2/ws/install/pytorch_controller/lib/libpytorch_controller.so: undefined symbol: zip_open

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(pytorch_controller)

# Default to C++23
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# check if 'third_party' folder exists and if not, download libtorch
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libtorch")
  message(WARNING "Downloading libtorch")
  execute_process(
    COMMAND mkdir third_party
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )
  execute_process(
    COMMAND wget https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-2.4.1%2Bcpu.zip
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party
  )
  execute_process(
COMMAND unzip libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-2.4.1+cpu.zip
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party
  )
endif()

# add CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to find PyTorch - use current path with 'thrid_party' folder
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libtorch")

# find ROS2 dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_common REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_core REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_util REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_costmap_2d REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(nav2_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(pluginlib REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml_cpp_vendor REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

# find PyTorch
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

nav2_package()

include_directories(
  include
)

set(ament_dependencies
  rclcpp
  geometry_msgs
  nav2_costmap_2d
  pluginlib
  nav_msgs
  nav2_util
  nav2_core
  tf2
  yaml_cpp_vendor
  yaml-cpp
  ZLIB
)

add_library(pytorch_controller SHARED
        src/pytorch_controller.cpp)

# prevent pluginlib from using boost
# use project name to define preprcessor variable ROS_PACKAGE_NAME
target_compile_definitions(pytorch_controller PUBLIC "PLUGINLIB__DISABLE_BOOST_FUNCTIONS" "ROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"${PROJECT_NAME}\"")
target_link_libraries(pytorch_controller "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" ZLIB::ZLIB) 
ament_target_dependencies(pytorch_controller
  ${ament_dependencies}
)


install(TARGETS pytorch_controller
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

install (DIRECTORY models DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include/
)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(pytorch_controller)
ament_export_dependencies(${ament_dependencies})

pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(nav2_core pytorch_controller.xml)

ament_package()

And I have the following package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>pytorch_controller</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>A ROS Nav2 navigation controller allowing to load and execute PyTorch models in TorchScript format.</description>
  <license>GPL-3.0-only</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>nav2_common</depend>
  <depend>nav2_core</depend>
  <depend>nav2_util</depend>
  <depend>nav2_costmap_2d</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>nav2_msgs</depend>
  <depend>pluginlib</depend>
  <depend>tf2</depend>
  <depend>yaml_cpp_vendor</depend>
  <depend>ZLIB</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

I have no problem loading the controller in nav2 when using only PyTorch. The problem arises when linking to libzip.
